# My prefix is a guilty pleasure, My suffix is a nasty thing

Tags: riddle, rhyme

- My prefix is a guilty pleasure.
- My suffix is a nasty thing.
- My infix is in total measure.
- My whole comes out in spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Butterfly

My prefix is a guilty pleasure.

> Butter -> butter tastes wonderful, but you shouldn't eat too much.

My suffix is a nasty thing.

> Fly -> a fly is a nasty thing.

My infix is in total measure.

> utter -- meaning complete; absolute.

My whole comes out in spring.

> Butterflies appear in the spring.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is probably not right because of the infix part, but the other 3 fit so well I thought I should share it.

> Cheatgrass 
>  Prefix and suffix are slangs, pretty self explanatory 
>  I don't really understand the infix condition, but either heat can be used as a unit of measure, or you can only measure the total heat of a reaction (not really true)? 
>  Cheatgrass is a plant that germinates in either the winter or spring

Comment: Bob Marley is currently turning in his grave

Comment: Sorry, not the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is

> Sparrow

My prefix is a guilty pleasure.

> **Spa** = a commercial establishment offering health and beauty treatment through such means as steam baths, exercise equipment, and massage.

My suffix is a nasty thing.

> **Row** = a noisy acrimonious quarrel.

My infix is in total measure.

> **Par** = an amount taken as an average or norm (there are several other relevant definitions of the word par which can be applicable here).

My whole comes out in spring.

> **Sparrows** appear to "come out" (be more frequently seen) in the springtime through a combination of migratory behaviour and a tendency to shelter for warmth during the winter season.

Comment: Sorry, not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Sweet Tooth

> A sweet can be a guilty pleasure.

> A tooth can be nasty when it is removed.

> EET TOOT is in TOTal mEasurE

> Due to the abundance of chocolate in easter one might develop a Sweet Tooth

Comment: Valentine's Day is in winter...

Comment: Go away Ralph Fiennes

Comment: Sorry, not the answer.